# Use variable in another function then use that function in the first function as an if statement

Tags: python

```
def secondscene():
  second_options = ['1','2','3','4']
  second_choice = ""
  n = 25
  while n > 0:
    print('''The lion has''', n, '''health, how do you attack the lion:
1.  Slash
2.  Chop
3.  Stab
4.  Block''')
    second_choice = input(str('Please enter a number between 1-3:'))
    if second_choice == second_options[0]:
      slash()
    else:
      print('please input one of the following listed numbers')

def slash():
  import random
  s = random.randint (1,10)
  n = n - s
```

Can someone please explain to me how to use "n" in another function then use that function in the if statement. I'm trying to get the attacks all to do different damage. Thanks.

Comment: You should pass the variable as an argument to the function and then the function should return a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a really basic question and you should start to see how to use POO in python which can be usefull for you.

```py
def secondscene():
  second_options = ['1','2','3','4']
  second_choice = ""
  n = 25
  while n > 0:
    print('''The lion has''', n, '''health, how do you attack the lion:
1.  Slash
2.  Chop
3.  Stab
4.  Block''')
    second_choice = input(str('Please enter a number between 1-3:'))
    if second_choice == second_options[0]:
      n = slash(n)
    else:
      print('please input one of the following listed numbers')

def slash(n):
  import random
  s = random.randint (1,10)
  n = n - s
  return n
```

Comment: Oh wow thanks man appreciate it, sorry I'm a beginner